# Update content of dynamic rows Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

[image]

In the above picture, I have column `Check-in hours` and `Time Left` which is a countdown timer that is based on the `Check-in hours` column.

As you can see, the first row has only **2 hours and 36 mins** which is based in the `Check in hours` column that has **3 hours**. Which is correct.

However the second row also has **2 hours and 36 mins** but has the `check in hours` value of `12 hours`.

Here's my **JS code:**

```
function makeTimer() {
var ROOMid = $("#row_id").text();
$.get('/get-time-out?id=' + ROOMid,function(data){
    hms = data[0].time_out + " GMT+08:00";
    console.log(hms)
});

var endTime = new Date(hms);            
endTime = (Date.parse(endTime) / 1000);

var now = new Date();
now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

var timeLeft = endTime - now;

var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400); 
var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60);
var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));

if(days == 0 && hours == 0 && 1 > minutes){
    $("#days").html("<strong><u>TIME OUT</u></strong>");
    $("#minutes").html("");
    $("#hours").html("");
    $("#seconds").html("");
}else if(0 > days){
    $("#days").html("<strong><u>TIME OUT</u></strong>");
    $(".minutes").html("");
    $(".hours").html("");
    $(".seconds").html("");
}else{
    $(".days").html(days + " days");
    $(".hours").html(hours + " hours");
    $(".minutes").html(minutes + " minutes");
    $(".seconds").html(seconds + " seconds");       
}
}
```

Here's my **blade.php**

```
@foreach ($customers as $c)
                <tr>
                    <td hidden class="row_id" id="row_id">{{$c->id}}</td>
                    <td scope="row" class="font-weight-bold">{{$c->room}}</td>
                    <td>{{$c->room_type}}</td>
                    <td>{{$c->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$c->check_in_hrs}}</td>
                    <td id="time">
                        {{
                            $ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F Y H:i:s', $c->time_out)->format('d F y h:i A')
                        }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="timer" class="timer">
                            <div class="days timer">-</div>
                            <div class="hours timer">-</div>
                            <div class="minutes timer">-</div>
                            <div class="seconds timer">-</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{$c->assistant}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle lblue fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-times red fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in the code is that the function is independent of any other arguments therefore in both cases it returns same results.

What you would want to do is to re-write your code logic to accept at least a single argument that would determine how many hours needs to be calculated to return in the row.

Something like

```
function makeTimer(timeLeft) {

var ROOMid = $("#row_id").text();
$.get('/get-time-out?id=' + ROOMid,function(data){
    hms = data[0].time_out + " GMT+08:00";
    console.log(hms)
});

var endTime = new Date(hms);            
endTime = (Date.parse(endTime) / 1000);

var now = new Date();

now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

var timeLeft = endTime - now;
```

Then, in your code, where you need it, pass the amount of hours as `timeLeft` parameter in your function.